# Unable to see media library images and can't able to upload new image in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am unable to see media library images and not able to upload new images.

I have checked following things:

1. Folder permission:  uploads/ 755
2. clear browser  cache
3. Disabled all plugin and try but did not get any success

Wordpress version : 4.2.3.
Theme name :  Lensa

Comment: It may be plugin conflict issue. First deactivate your all plugins and then try to r-install your WordPress from dashboard > updates.then activate  your plugins one by one.

Comment: Once your WordPress is successfully updated, then activate your plugin one by one. Don't forgot to try and check uploading image after each plugin is activated. Plugin after which your image uploading stops is a culprit and  try to find some alternative for this plugin.